# Array spinner selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
int nvalue=2;
Spinner[] spinner = new Spinner[nvalue];
spinner[].setonitem?
```

I have the array of spinner and I want to use `setOnItemSelectedListener`  for every spinner.How can I use `setOnItemSelectedListener` for array spinner?

```
spinner[0].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }

    });
```

will shows error

Comment: did you imported "android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener" & "android.widget.Spinner"

Comment: yes i found that i need to import and now i imported above.i got nvalue(refer above code) via string in server. now how can i declare setOnItemSelectedListener for all spinners.pls give me a example

Comment: i tried for(int i=0;i<nvalue;i++){spinner[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() .... } but it will not worked out

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the Spinners in the Array and just didn't add the code snippet?
You can set one listener for all your spinners but you have to initialize them by either inflating them from xml or creating them with Java.

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: i tried like for(int i=0;i<nvalue;i++){spinner[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() .... } . but it will not worked out. pls give me an example

Comment: You need to do something like this: for(int i=0; i<nvalue; i++) { spinner[i] = new Spinner(this); spinner[i].setOnItem ... } - the Spinner needs to be initialized with the context. If you're defining them in XML you need to do the Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1); flow

Comment: for( nSpinerCount=0;nSpinerCount<BusSearch.NoOfPass;nSpinerCount++)
  {
   BoardingSpinner[nSpinerCount]= new Spinner(this);
   BoardingSpinner[nSpinerCount].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
   {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
      nIndex = BoardingSpinner[nSpinerCount].getSelectedItemPosition();    
    }
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {
           nIndex = BoardingSpinner[nSpinerCount].getSelectedItemPosition();    
    }
   
   });
  } but it will not call if select

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the code you've got, it looks as though you may not be instantiating the actual spinners. The line `Spinner[] spinner = new Spinner[nvalue];` instantiates the array of Spinners, but the value of each `Spinner` in the array at this point is `null` by default. So  if you're trying to call `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on a null value, a null pointer exception will be thrown. Hence, you have to do something like `spinner[0] = new Spinner(context)` create a new `Spinner` instance, and then call `spinner[0].setOnItemSelectedListener()`.

EDIT: Answered already by Tim :-)